# How to check pregnancy at home?

Tags: obstetrics

Is there any way to check pregnancy at home.I have used prega-news to check but i am not sure how much it is useful.Can any one suggest me some better option.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Without access to a doctor, a home pregnancy test is the most accurate way. It measures the amount of a hormone (hCG) in your urine (see for example [WebMD's site on pregnancy tests](http://www.m.webmd.com/baby/guide/pregnancy-tests) for more information on how it works) .

The other two reliable methods are a blood test for the same hormone and an ultrasound (usually conclusive starting from week 3 after conception), but these are not something that can be done at home. While you will find other methods on the internet, most of them are unproven and all of them will be less reliable than a home pregnancy test or a blood test.

A study found that while urine tests are less accurate than blood tests, the difference in reliability is not that big:

> Overall, the whole blood pregnancy test was 95.8% sensitive (negative predictive value 97.9%), whereas the urine test was 95.3% sensitive (negative predictive value 97.6%); the specificity and positive predictive value of both tests was 100%.

(from [" Substituting Whole Blood for Urine in a Bedside Pregnancy Test"](http://www.jem-journal.com/article/S0736-4679(11)00538-5/abstract) ) That means that urine tests have more false negative (not picking up pregnancy) , but there were no false positives in the study.

From a Google search it looks like what you are referencing in your question is a standard home pregnancy test and thus your best available method.